# How can `if barstate.isconfirmed` section be run twice per bar?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Why does `if barstate.isconfirmed` section run twice per bar in this script:
(please see the prints on realtime (only realtime!) bars https://www.tradingview.com/x/JKuAfJKg/)

The manual reads:

> "Returns true if the script is calculating the last (closing) update of the current bar. The next script calculation will be on the new bar data."

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © moebius1977
//@version=5
indicator("barstate.isconfirmed runs twice", overlay = true)

type someStupidObject
    float y

updateLabel(someStupidObject _obj) =>
    varip _s = ""
    _obj.y := 1

    // this section runs twice per bar - why?
    if barstate.isconfirmed 
        _s := str.length(_s) > 50 ? str.substring(_s, str.length(_s) - 50) : _s
        _s += "\nB" + str.tostring(bar_index) +"✔"
    _lbl = label.new(bar_index, high, _s, color = color.yellow, textcolor = color.black)

clearStringArray(someStupidObject _obj, string[] _htfBuffer) =>
    _obj.y := 0
    array.clear(_htfBuffer) 

var obj1 = someStupidObject.new()

type rsReturn
    string[]    stringArray1  

var naRsRet = rsReturn.new(stringArray1     = array.new<string>())
nzo(rsReturn _rsRet) => na(_rsRet) ? naRsRet : _rsRet 
trivialFunc(rsReturn _rsRet) => _rsRet

var rsRet = rsReturn.new(stringArray1       = array.new<string>())

rsRet := request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "240", (timeframe.period == "240") ? trivialFunc(rsRet) : na, lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_off)
rsRet := nzo(rsRet) // if na then substitute for a dummy empty object

clearStringArray(obj1, rsRet.stringArray1)

plotchar(bar_index, "bar_index","", location.belowbar)

updateLabel(obj1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe its because you are using a VARIP which uses the intraday data instead of a VAR of _S

Comment: Well, I do not know how can I check whether `isconfirmed` section performs twice on realtime bars without using `varip` vars. To me this seems quite a legal use of `varip` and of `barstate.isconfirmed`.

Answer (score 0):

From the support:

> "The technical team confirmed this is not a bug but the expected
> behavior of the barstate.isconfirmed variable. For example:   1) the
> last bar for the current timeframe confirmed —> script calculated and
> barstate.isconfirmed is true. 2) the last bar for the higher timeframe
> confirmed —> script calculated again and barstate.isconfirmed is still
> true."